# How to write author names according to research paper or journal below title (in LaTeX)

Tags: journal, research

How do I write author names according to a  research paper or journal below title (in LaTeX)
For Example:

```
                   **Research Paper Title Name**
             B.K.Author1, Dr. S B Author2, Dr. V. M. Author3
   1. Research Scholar, CHLR (Computer Science), ABC College, ABC Dist, Email:abs.cse@abc.edu.in
   2. HOD, Dept. of Computer Science, Pqr College, Place, s.b.author.pqr@gmail.com
   3. Associate Prof, Dept. of Electronics and Computer Science, ABC College, 
      xyz@rediffmail.com
```

Please Share command for the above format in LaTeX

Comment: Hi @Anagha and welcome to TeX-SE. Please verify [How to use BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) and [Bibliography management with bibtex](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_bibtex).

Comment: @fhz: apparently this question is not about the authors in a reference but about authors of a paper  and their affiliations that are shown right after the paper title.

Comment: Probably you should use `\authors{B. K. Author ...}, ` that will not show until you use `\maketitle`, but  the way to set authors and specially the affiliation could change according to  the document class, so we should now if you are using `article`, `paper`, or whatever.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context here, since the title construction typically depends on the journal. Do you know the journal? Do they provide a template? Can you provide the basic construction related to your output (in the form of a minimal example)?

Comment: Depending on the journal, these may also provide document templates. Elsevier for example provides a documentclass that will do this for you!

Comment: What template are you using? Typically an helpful LaTeX example is attached to it, e.g. https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS provides a "simplified" version of Springers Lecture Notes in Computer SScience (LNCS) template.